# Google Civic Information API `/voterInfoQuery` route returning 400

Tags: google-civic-information-api

When testing the API at this site (https://developers.google.com/civic-information/docs/v2/elections/voterInfoQuery) I only receive a `400` response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "invalid",
    "message": "Election unknown"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "Election unknown"
 }
}
```

is this API still supported?

Answer (score -3):

Yes, the API is still supported. Did you resolve the issue?

If not, make sure you're putting in a valid number for the electionId (2000 should work).